# How to make 70 bytes .class file print "Hello World"?

Tags: java

I am referring below article about the 70 bytes java class file that prints Hello World.

http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0707/richards/index.html

I downloaded the source code, compiled GenClass5.java and executed it to generate the 70 bytes class file. The generated class doesn't have a name and it has only the extension .class. My question is how do I execute it with java to print Hello World?

Comment: Java is a bit fussy about filenames - try changing your filename to hello or your class name to GenClass5.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't have a name"? Is the file literally just `.class`? If so, then it actually doesn't have an extension

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the steps. Can you share how you compiled GenClass5.java? I'm getting `error: class, interface, or enum expected` when trying to `javac`.

Comment: Oh I'm not supposed to compile the code listed on the webpage. Instead, downloading the zip and compiling/running GenClass5.java will produce a 70-byte file named ".class".

Comment: This might have to do with Java versions, notice that the article was published in 2004. In particular, `java sun.security.util.PropertyExpander 'Hello World!'` says there is no main method, contrary to what the article implies.

Comment: "The restrictions were that the class must execute under Sun's 1.3 JRE". I don't have that, and I think this behavior depends on it, so unfortunately I'll have to give up on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still run `java MyClassName`, it's just that the classname is now the empty string. To make the shell pass an empty string, put it in quotes:

```
java ""
```

Unfortunately, since it depends on the internals of a class that has changed since the article was written, you just get an error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class , please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

but this is true even with a full size class.